# Difference between methods

Tags: ruby

Other than syntax, is there any benefit to running either of these methods over the other? Will one be lighter on a server or use less resources?

```
def get_grade(grade)
  if grade.to_i >= 90
    "A"
  elsif (grade >= 79) && (grade <= 89)
    "B"
  elsif (grade >= 68) && (grade <= 79)
    "C"
  elsif (grade >= 58) && (grade <= 69)
    "D"
  else
    "F"
  end
end
```

or

```
def get_grade(num)
  if num >= 90
     puts "A"
  elsif num >= 80
     puts "B"
  elsif num >= 70
     puts "C"
  elsif num >= 60
     puts "D"
  else
     puts "F"
  end
end
```

Comment: They look completely different. In different context, you may want to use different ones.

Comment: Premature optimisation can lead into a unvalued code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More idiomatic Ruby would be

```
case grade
when 90..100
  "A"
when 80...90
  "B"
when 70...80
  "C"
when 60...70
  "D"
else
  "F"
end
```

For optimization purposes, minor changes like this are insignificant. You should be much more concerned about what is more readable/understandable/maintainable.